# Shell: Неправильно работает rename

Tags: shell

У меня есть файл, название которого с пробелами, чтобы заменить пробелы на нижние подчёркивания, я использовал команду `rename \  _ /storage/emulated/0/Download/f\ i\ l\ e.py` (название файла: `f i l e.py`), я ожидал, что файл будет называться так: `f_i_l_e.py`, но заменился один пробел, и теперь название файла: `f_i l e.py`. Как решить эту проблему?

Comment: Используйте команду `mv` (и `man mv`)

Answer (score 0):

судя по приведённому синтаксису аргументов, вы использовали реализацию программы *rename* из пакета `util-linux`. эта реализация, к сожалению, умеет делать лишь однократную замену переданной первым аргументом строки на строку, переданную вторым аргументом.

чтобы с помощью неё произвести несколько замен (одной и той же строки), можно запустить её несколько раз подряд.

---

существует и иная реализация этой программы, на языке *perl* (отсюда её дополнительное имя — `prename`), которой первым аргументом передаётся регулярное выражение. для приведённого в вопросе примера вызов может выглядеть так:

```
$ prename 's/ /_/g' путь/к/файлам
```

дополнительным бонусом является понимание этой реализацией программы *rename* опции `-n` (`--no-act`), при наличии которой программа лишь выведет список своих действий (какие имена на какие могут быть изменены), не выполняя при этом реального переименования файлов.